# How can i make a link to open in browser instead of WebView App

Tags: android

I created a WebView App and it's working fine but there is a link which I want it to open in the default browser instead of that app what can I do.

Comment: Hello @therental, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `WebViewClient` to your `webView` (if not already added) and then override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading ()` method:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url) {
        if (url.contains(myUrl)) {
            Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myUrl);
            context.startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        } else {
            return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(webview, url);
        }
     }      
}
```

This way your are telling your `webview` to not continue loading a specific `url`. Instead, launch the proper application (mostly a browser) to handle the `url`.